# script sh syntax error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP='192.168.1.1'
fping -c1 -t300 $IP 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
if [ "$?" = 0 ]
then
    echo "Host found"
else
    echo "Host not found"
fi
```

When I try to run it, this is the outcome:

```
$ sh /home/pi/sh/test.sh         
/home/pi/sh/test.sh: 9: /home/pi/sh/test.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add the output of `file /home/pi/sh/test.sh`. I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: Working for me..also you have used `bash` shebang, call it as `bash /home/pi/sh/test.sh ` ..

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ bash /home/pi/sh/test.sh
/home/pi/sh/test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/home/pi/sh/test.sh: line 9: `fi'

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037627/i-try-to-do-the-script

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the script contains some CR (\r) characters. If you have edited this script from windows, that would explain why. Running this should reveal the otherwise "invisible" carriage return characters:

```
sed -n l /home/pi/sh/test.sh
```

(That's lowercase L, not 1).
If you see a `\r` in the above, see [FAQ 52](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052) for various ways to get rid of them.

On a side note, don't put `.sh` extension on a bash script, and don't run a bash script with `sh`.

Comment: "don't put .sh extension on a bash script"? Eh, what? Why?

Comment: @muru, because bash is not sh, so it's misleading. Furthermore, [commands should not have extensions at all](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful).

Comment: What does `bash` not being `sh` have to do with an extension that is common to `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `ash`, `dash`, `csh`, `tcsh` and who knows what else and has decades of convention behind it? And what do I care about some random fellows rambling's? -1 for nonsense.

Comment: @muru, Then Ubuntu does not follow this old "convention" of yours. Most of the scripts in your ubuntu install has no extension.

Comment: Because packaging guidelines recommend that scripts in PATH shouldn't have extensions, so that a change in language does not involve a change in executable name. It is equally applicable to scripts in other languages, such as Python.

Comment: @muru, exactly.

Comment: Ah, so you are a troll. Ok, thanks, but no thanks.